# change output location of plugin function using a custom hook

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks, actions, youtube

I'm running the [YouTube Video Fetcher plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-video-fetcher/) and it fetches youtube videos and displays it on your website. However, instead of displaying the video after the post, I want to hook the code into a custom container.

Here is the function in the plugin used to display the video after the post:

```
//The below function is used to display the video after the post.
function append_the_video($content){
    return $content.youtube_video();
}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');
```

I tried swapping out the following line:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');
```

with this line but it is not working:

```
add_action('my_custom_hook_name', 'append_the_video');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like what you are doing should work but I think you have a couple of things going wrong.

First, it sounds like you've hacked the plugin. Don't do that, just remove the callback from the `the_content` hook.

In your theme's `functions.php` add:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');
```

The `youtube_video()` function [depends on the `$post` variable](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/youtube-video-fetcher/trunk/youtube_video.php#L18). That means it is an essentially "Loop-only" function.  You can't move it outside the Loop if that is what you are trying to do. It won't work correctly.

You can run it in a different location by adding your own callback to `the_content`.

```
function my_prepend_the_video($content){
    return youtube_video().$content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_prepend_the_video');
```

And of course, you can add other markup if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Any chance I can output the youtube video into a div container? For instance, I run the following function (as an example) to pull a custom field value into a custom container.

`function post_spotify_embed() { 
  global $post; 
  $spotifyembed = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'spotify-embed', true); 
  if ($spotifyembed) 
  echo '<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=' . $spotifyembed . '" width="640" height="720" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>'; 
} 
add_action('hook_top_embed_code','post_spotify_embed',0);`

Or is this still not possible?

Comment: Of course, add the `div` markup to the filter callback.